# Why does the blur modifier affect views differently?

Tags: swiftui

I spent a lot of time trying to figure out whether this was a bug, but I couldn't for the life of me figure out why a shape wasn't blurring correctly.

```
VStack {
    //Doesn't blur right
    Capsule()
        .fill(LinearGradient(colors: [Color.red, Color.blue], startPoint: .leading, endPoint: .trailing))
        .frame(width: 80, height: 40)
        .blur(radius: 10)
    //Does blur correctly
    HStack {
    }
    .frame(width: 80, height: 40)
    .background(
        LinearGradient(colors: [Color.red, Color.blue], startPoint: .leading, endPoint: .trailing)
    )
    .clipShape(Capsule())
    .blur(radius: 10)
}
```

[image]

When you apply blur to an empty HStack, it blurs correctly, while using a blur to a shape doesn't. **Can someone explain why it differs?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, two of them looks like the same but it's not the same.

From Apple docs, `Capsule()` is subclass of `Shape` which is subclass of `View`.

The first one, when you using `Capsule()` directly then you `.fill` means just like you add subview `LinearGradient` with colors into `Capsule()`. That's the reason I think `.blur` not working correctly when you call directly from `Capsule()`.

The second one, you `.blur` correctly because the view was directly be drawn on view ( just like drawing in layer of view in normal UIKit)

The view hierarchy show the different between two of them.
[image: Example]

The solution:
You can do like your second view

```swift
HStack {
}
.frame(width: 80, height: 40)
.background(
    LinearGradient(colors: [Color.red, Color.blue], startPoint: .leading, endPoint: .trailing)
)
.clipShape(Capsule())
.blur(radius: 10)
```

Or you can make linear gradient with mask

```swift
HStack {
    LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [.red, .blue]), startPoint: .leading, endPoint: .trailing)
        .mask(
            Capsule()
            .blur(radius: 10)
            .frame(width: 80, height: 40)
        )
}.frame(width: 200, height: 60)
```

Both will act the same like you draw on the layer of view
[image: The result]

**UPDATE**

If you need it works directly, just use only one color then call `.foregroundColor` then blur will continue work - But only one color at the time only.

```swift
Capsule()
    .foregroundColor(Color.red)
    .blur(radius: 10)
    .frame(width: 80, height: 40)
```